# SQL Server / ADO.Net: entity with multi-part FK primary key, with one part optional?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, rdbms, ado.net-entity-data-model

Here's an SQL Server / ADO.Net Entity Framework question: I'm looking for the "best" way to do this.

I have a hierarchical structure of objects similar to the following:

```
Company -> Division -> Department -> Group -> Specialty
```

The primary key of each (other than Company) consists of a foreign key pointing to the PK of each of its ancestors.  So, Specialty looks like this:

```
[PK/FK] CompanyID (string)
[PK/FK] DivisionID (int)
[PK/FK] DepartmentID (int)
[PK/FK] GroupID (int)
[PK]    SpecialtyID (int)
        Name (string)
        Description (string)
```

This basic structure has to remain in place for reasons I won't go into - so using a GUID as the PK really isn't in the cards -- we have to interface with other apps that rely on the "Bergdorf.6.3.4.1" ID construct that this structure reflects.

What I need to do now, though, is add the ability to add a Specialty which applies to an entire Department, rather than to a group.  So, in an ideal world, we'd have this:

```
[PK/FK] CompanyID (string)
[PK/FK] DivisionID (int)
[PK/FK] DepartmentID (int)
[PK/FK] GroupID (int/NULL)
[PK]    SpecialtyID (int)
        Name (string)
        Description (string)
```

...such that if the Specialty's GroupID is null, that means it applies to the whole department.

But, of course, you can't have a nullable field as part of a PK.  So that's a no-go.

It also won't work to just pull GroupID out of the PK, because then SpecialtyID is going to have to be unique across an entire Department, and we already have established IDs that make that impossible.

Can't make a "special" GroupID (e.g. "-1") that means "No Group", because the FK constraints would require us to create a Group with an ID of -1 for every single Department.

...So... what's the right thing to do here?  Do I have to make a GUID for Specialty, and pull all those FKs out of the PK?  Would really like to avoid that if possible.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have two (subtype) base tables with no nullable columns: one for Department Specialties and another for Group Specialties. You'll probably want a third (supertype) table for all specialities so that you can have `SpecialtyID` values that are unique to all Specialties regardless of subtype.

Then you coould have a `VIEW` that `UNION`s the subtypes together and here you can introduce a default value (e.g. `-1`) for the 'missing' `GroupID`s for Department Specialities. You could go further and only expose the `VIEW`, don't expose the base tables and use `INSTEAD OF` triggers on the `VIEW` to hande updates to the base table.

You would anyhow need a mechanism to ensure that for every Specialty (supertype) created **exactly one** Department Specialty or Group Specialty is also created e.g. you could revoke all write permissions on all realted base tables and `VIEW`s and force users to create Specialties uses CRUD procedures you've coded to ensure the super/subtype requirements are always satisfied.

Comment: This is definitely an option.  Will give it a test run.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "null-buster" computed column, based on the nullable `GroupID` column, and make it part of the PK instead of `GroupID`:

```
create table Specialities (
    CompanyID varchar(10) not null,
    DivisionID int not null,
    DepartmentID int not null,
    GroupID int null,
    SpecialityID int not null,
    Name varchar(10) not null,
    Description varchar(max) not null,
    _NNGroupID as ISNULL(GroupID,-1),
    constraint PK_Specialities PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID,DivisionID,DepartmentID,_NNGroupID,SpecialityID)
)
```

I'm not sure whether I like this idea or not, but it may be an option for you. This assumes that no real `GroupID` of -1 will ever exist - you may have to pick a different magic value for your purposes. So long as the value on the right-hand side of the `ISNULL` is not part of the domain of real `GroupID`s, this should work.

You continue to have the foreign key defined against `GroupID` rather than `_NNGroupID` so that the nullable-ness of the foreign key constraint works as you expect.

Comment: this sounds like a pretty good option, but how would I align this with the ADO.Net entity framework?

Comment: I've not tried to achieve such mappings myself - I can give advice on pure SQL, but how it works with ORMs is a mystery to me - I still try to write most of my SQL directly.

Comment: Thanks; I'll look into it and post here if I figure out a way to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an xref table linking Specialty with Department: `xSpecialtyDepartment(SpecialtyID int, DepartmentID int)`

Comment: Not sure I understand how that would solve the problem?   please elaborate... thanks!

Comment: Specialty is a child of Group, and Specialty.GroupID is nullable, correct? And do I understand correctly that Group is a child of Department?

Comment: The idea behind the xref table is simply to allow a many-to-many relationship between Specialty and Department.